# How to add auto completion list in monaco

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I am using Monaco Editor in my electron application. I want to add auto completion list instead of overriding it. Before adding auto complete list:

[image]

After adding auto complete list only added keyword are in the list. but also want words from document:

[image]

*this image is from monaco playground but i also experiencing same behavior*

I am using the following code:

```
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('mylang', {
   provideCompletionItems: () => {
      return [
        // keywords detail
      ]
   }
})
```